# how to get a binomial from a summation

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation

An urn contains 6 Red balls and 1 Blue ball. A fair die having faces f1;2;3;4;5;6g is
rolled. If the top face on the die shows m, then m random balls are removed from the urn.
What is the expected number of Red balls removed by this process?

---

i have the following in my solutions,

$$\frac{1}{6} \sum_{k=1}^{6} \frac{6}{7}k = \frac{1}{6}\frac{6}{7}\binom{7}{2}$$

can someone please explain where the 7 choose 2 comes from or rather how to get it from the summation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\binom{n+1}{2}$$

Comment: thanks, is there a name that describes this function?

Comment: @notamathwiz Yes, I think so, but I can't recall it now. See [here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~erowland/sumsofpowers.html) for a proof and more.

Comment: @notamathwiz  That's the simplest case of [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula).